# How to wrap text on MathJax using React( with material-ui and react-mathjax-node)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mathjax

I have tried to word wrapping.
I have written this code below.

```js
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MathJax from "@innodoc/react-mathjax-node";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  text: {
    overflowWrap: "break-word",
  },
}));

function Example() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
    <Typography className={classes.text}>
      <MathJax.Provider>
        <MathJax.MathJaxNode texCode="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
      </MathJax.Provider>
    </Typography>
  )
}
```

I have used material-ui for styling.
However it does not work.
I have attached screenshot how it looks in sufficiently small-width view of Google Chrome on Mac (M1).

[image]

How to word wrapping for MathJax in React?

Answer (score 0):

This because the root element of the formula (`<mjx-math>`) has the style `word-wrap: nowrap` which prevents the words to break.

You can override this style using whatever css technique you're using. Having said that without `word-wrap: nowrap` the equation might [look bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMjSZ.png) so I'm not sure you should do it.

For example

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  text: {
    overflowWrap: "break-word",
    width: 100,
    "*": {
      whiteSpace: "normal"
    }
  }
}));
```

Breaks the formula.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-easley-loyfj

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!

Sadly it do not change in my case.
Since a character is an element in the html sense( e.g. "aaa" is the complex of three MathJax elements) it might be not valid to "word-wrap".

( I will use paper's title only. This is almost alphabet, but is sometimes include to math-words. Thank you for your kindness!)

Comment: Sure :)
Please don't use an answer for comments but either update your question or comment to your question / my answer. Or, the best way is to actually show what you've done to solve this so other people can benefit your solution. Happy coding :)

Comment: Sure :D I created an account yesterday. Thank you for teaching!

Comment: NP, let's do it :)